# Traversing the optimum path between nodes

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

in a graph where there are multiple path to go from point (:A) to (:B) through node (:C), I'd like to extract paths from (:A) to (:B) through nodes of type (c:C) where c.Value is maximum. For instance, connect all movies with only their oldest common actors.

```
match p=(m1:Movie) <-[:ACTED_IN]- (a:Actor) -[:ACTED_IN]-> (m2:Movie) 
return m1.Name, m2.Name, a.Name, max(a.Age)
```

The above query returns the proper age for the oldest actor, but not always his correct name.

Conversely, I noticed that the following query returns both correct age and name.

```
match p=(m1:Movie) <-[:ACTED_IN]- (a:Actor) -[:ACTED_IN]-> (m2:Movie) 
with m1, m2, a order by a.age desc
return m1.name, m2.name, a.name, max(a.age), head(collect(a.name))
```

Would this always be true? I guess so.
I there a better way to do the job without sorting which may cost much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are willing to do similar things, consider read [this post](http://neo4j.com/blog/common-confusions-cypher/#comment-55165) from [@_nicolemargaret](https://twitter.com/neo4j/status/705150778340720640) which describe how to extract the n oldest actors acting in pairs of movies rather than just the first, as with head(collect()).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` for this:

```
match p=(m1:Movie) <-[:ACTED_IN]- (a:Actor) -[:ACTED_IN]-> (m2:Movie) 
return m1.Name, m2.Name, a.Name, a.Age order by a.Age desc limit 1
```

Be aware that you basically want to do a weighted shortest path. Neo4j can do this more efficiently using java code and the `GraphAlgoFactory`, see the chapter on this in the reference manual.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to perform a weighted shortest path and unfortunately I'm not able to write java. Using limit 1 doesn't return the proper result. It only returns - from my testing - the shortest path rather than all shortest paths. My intension was to return connected movies and the oldest of their common actors. My code does the job, but I was wondering if a more elegant and efficient code would exist.

Comment: I don't find efficient to first collect names, hence filter out the first.